# Problem with references in classic thesis if algorithm2e package is used

Tags: cross-referencing, algorithm2e, classicthesis

If I use the `algorithm2e` package together with the `linesnumbered` option and the `classicthesis` package, references to a sub sub section are wrong. If I don't use the `linesnumbered` option, references are correct. Is this a bug? Is there a work-around?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ruled, vlined, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}  % references NOT OK
%\usepackage[ruled, vlined]{algorithm2e}  % references OK

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}

Wrong reference -> \ref{label}

\subsection{Section}

\begin{algorithm}[htbp]
  \LinesNumbered
  i = 1
\end{algorithm}

\subsubsection{Sub Sub Section}
\label{label}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\label` picks up the most recent `\@currentlabel` that is set. And, in your case, this *is* the line inside the `algorithm` when you have `linesnumbered` activated. If your intent is to have a hyperlink point to the start of the subsection, you either need to insert a `\phantomsection` and update `\@currentlabel` to the appropriate counter *manually*

```
\makeatletter
\def\@currentlabel{\thesubsection}% Update reference text
\makeatother
\phantomsection% Mark hyperref link location
\subsubsection{Sub Sub Section}
\label{label}
```

or you need to update the counter `secnumdepth` to actually also have your sub-sub-sections also numbered:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}% Number up to \subsubsection
```

In the former case, the reference will show `1.0.1` (the value contained within `\thesubsection`) but point to the sub-sub-section. In the latter case, the reference will be correctly pointing to the sub-sub-section *and* have the appropriate number.

[image]